# How to calculate distance between two GeoPoints with Android MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know the distance of two points or the width and height distance of my current mapview in km unit. Is there any android map api to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not Map API, but the Android SDK's Location class has methods like

```
distanceBetween
```

and

```
distanceTo
```

Check them out [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/Location.html)