# mapView overlay items from mysql database

Tags: java, android, mysql, google-maps

I am new to Android and have run into a bit of an issue:

I created a map view and need to get my overlay items from mysql database, there are numerous points of interest in the database so i need to limit it to say the 50 closest pois to the user. Firstly, how do i get the info from my database to appear as ovelay? and secondly how do i limit it to x amount closest point to the users location?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) where you can see how to show overlay on map.

And to show first 50 locations my Idea is ,

1st.In Database Store the Distances from Current location.

2nd. Fetch them in ascending order.

3rd.Then show only first 50 items in MapView

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077994/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-geopoints-with-android-mapview) to calculate distance between to points

[Study about the maps](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Answer (score 0):

First get all the latitudes and longitudes from the database and then calculate the distance from the current location. Then find out 50 distances those are nearer to your current location and store them in a map, then try to create overlays...